# Latex labels with seaborn

Tags: python, plot, label, seaborn

I'm trying to plot with seaborn.kdeplot with LaTeX labels. What I tried is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(font_scale=1.5, rc={'text.usetex' : True})

x = np.linspace(-50,50,100)
y = np.sin(x)**2/x

fig = plt.figure(1)
sns.set_style('white')
sns.kdeplot(np.array(y), label='hey')
fig.gca().set(xlabel=r'$e(t_0)$ [s]', ylabel='PDF')
fig.savefig("seaborntest.png", close = True, verbose = True)
```

Running this I've got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sns_problem.py", line 17, in <module>
    fig.savefig("seaborntest.png", close = True, verbose = True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1363, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2093, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 491, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 439, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 999, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1050, in draw
    renderer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 999, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 752, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 304, in _get_layout
    ismath=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 196, in get_text_width_height_descent
    texmanager = self.get_texmanager()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 597, in get_texmanager
    self._texmanager = TexManager()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 137, in __init__
    ff = rcParams['font.family'].lower()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

What could be the problem? The strange thing is that I got this error even if I remove the line adding the labels. What is the proper way of using LaTeX in seaborn plot labels?

Comment: You code work perfectly for me. May be your installation of latex is corrupted?

Comment: Thanks, It's good to know that it works for you. I think it's not a latex problem, because I use latex regularly and I haven't noticed anything like that. Maybe it could be the problem of my seaborn installation. By the way, I evaded the problem with using PyQt-Fit instead of seaborn.

Comment: The only issue I see is the bottom of the image is a little clipped.

Comment: Works fine for me too (python3, matplotlib 3.3.2, seaborn 0.11.0). What are your versions of the modules? Have you tried with python3?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have latex install on your machine, this could be causing errors.

For Linux users try installing Latex:

```
sudo apt update 

sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended dvipng cm-super
```

If in notebook, restart the Kernel, and then the font should display using Latex.